# Close SideBar with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sidebar

I need to close my sidebar with JavaScript. I try with the following code, but when I click on the icon that executes the opening of the sidebar, it simply does not open it anymore because the **display:none** is executed immediately.

This is my code with which I open and close the SideBar:

```
function openNavCategories() { 
    const overlayContent = document.getElementById('overlayContent-categories');

    document.getElementById('nav-categories').style.width = '30%';
    overlayContent.style.display = 'block';
    overlayContent.style.width = '100%';
    document.getElementById('category-icon').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('category-icon-open').style.display = 'block';
}

function closeNavCategories() {
    const navCategories = document.getElementById('nav-categories');
    navCategories.style.width = '0%';
    navCategories.style.transition = 'all 0.4s';
    document.getElementById('overlayContent-categories').style.display = 'none';
}
```

And this one with which I try to verify that the click is outside of my SideBar but it does not even show it anymore:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    var SideBar = document.getElementById('nav-categories');
    if(event.target != SideBar && event.target.parentNode != SideBar ) {
        SideBar.style.display = 'none';
    }
})
```

**And this is my HTML and SCSS:**

```
    <a href="#" class="closeBtn-categories" onclick="closeNavCategories()">X</a>

    <div id="overlayContent-categories" class="overlay__content-categories">
        <h2>Categorías</h2>
        <a href="#" onclick="closeNavCategories()">Categoría 1</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="closeNavCategories()">Categoría 2</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="closeNavCategories()">Categoría 3</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="closeNavCategories()">Categoría 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
    .overlay-categories {
      position: fixed;
      top:0;
      right:0; // de derecha
      width: 0%;
      height: 100%;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
      overflow-x: hidden;
      z-index: 10;
      transition: all 0.8s; 

      h2 {
        color: #506a80;
        margin: .2rem 0 .5rem 0rem;
      }

      a {
        padding: 10px;
        color: #ccc;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        display:block;

        &:hover {
            color: #fff;
        }
      }

      .closeBtn-categories {
          position: absolute;
          top:20px;
          right: 35px;
          font-size: 2rem;
      }

      .overlay__content-categories {
          position: relative;
          display: none;
          top: 10%;
          width: 0%;
          text-align: center;
          margin-top: 20px;
          transition: all 2s linear;  
      }

  }
```

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Please share your html as well

Comment: and the 'nav-categories' wrap it all?

Comment: That's right, is the ID of the DIV that surrounds the sideBar: <div id="nav-categories" class="overlay-categories">

Answer (score 1):

You can define css class for the opened/closed style rather than manipulate style attribute in the script runtime. It let you keep all the styles one place in the SCSS.

```
  /* defined nav-categories__closed class*/
  #nav-categories{
    width: 30%;
    .overlayContent-categories{
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }

  #nav-categories.nav-categories__closed{
    width: 0%;
    transition: all 0.4s;

    .overlayContent-categories{
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

Modify `openNavCategories()` and `closeNavCategories()` to only toggling the `nav-categories__closed`

```
function openNavCategories() {
  const navCategories = document.getElementById('nav-categories');
  navCategories.classList.toggle('nav-categories__closed', false);

}

function closeNavCategories() {
  const navCategories = document.getElementById('nav-categories');
  navCategories.classList.toggle('nav-categories__closed', true);
}
```

You have a third function to close the sidebar when a click is performed outside the sidebar. You may need to modify the function to include in the checking: If the event target is also not the control to open the sidebar, then invoke `closeNavCategories()`. The purpose of `closeNavCategories()` and the core part of mouseup event more or less doing the same job: to close the sidebar. You can eliminate the repeating code by referring to the same function.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rgfbLyon/5/